# what is use of additional_data column in sales_flat_quote_item table?

Tags: magento-1.9, table, quoteitem, additional-information

I want to store add custom `id` (`id` is primary key of another table ) in `sales_flat_quote_item` table.

**Question.** create new column for `id`  or  add `id` in `additional_data` column ?

which answer is flexible from above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is create new field for the `id` because your use this field anywhere and also convert to `sales_flat_order_item` table easily.

Comment: Ok thanks but what is use of additional_data column in sales_flat_quote_item  table ?

Comment: It use for save some product additional information but you can save your custom field data also but best way like above ans..